# Android to-do list app with shared preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have a text field for entering the to-do, a spinner where the user chooses if it's work, personal, or other and I have a date/time picker. I need to save all those using shared preferences and then populate them in a table view on the main page. I am having trouble figuring out how to save them all and send them to the different columns on the main screen.

Comment: Please present what you've tried so far and be more specific about what isn't working. Example code showing what you've tried would really help others answer your question effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to save the value in SharedPreferences

```
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("id", "iddata");  
        editor.commit();
```

Use below code retrive value from  SharedPreferences

```
String id=pref.getString("id", null);
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all u need to create a java class that handles your session data and use get and set methods in order to set and get data using shared preference.

```
public class SessionManager
 {
   // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();
   SharedPreferences pref;

Editor editor;
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
 // Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "yourprefname";

private static final String KEY_IS_NAME = "isname";
private static final String KEY_IS_DATE="isdate";
private static final String KEY_IS_TIME="istime";

   public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();

}
 public void setTime(String time)
{
editor.putString(KEY_IS_TIME,time);
editor.commit();
}

public String getTime()
{
    return pref.getString(KEY_IS_TIME,null);
}
```

}

after that u need to use sessionManager class by creating object in any activity like

```
SessionManager session = new SessionManager(this);
//to set the values , use set method
session.setTime(time);
//to get the values, use get method
String time=Session.getTime();
```